# Is there an error with the following sentences?

Tags: grammar

I got the following sentences from an old book of grammar

Correct the error

1. Jupiter is almost so bright as Venus.

I think there is no error with grammar, but perhaps with knowledge
So, Venus is brighter than Jupiter. = both grammar and knowledge correct

2. The horse is swifter, but not so strong as the ox .
   correction : is swifter than......complete the rest
3. I fear lest we shall not arrive in season .

lest =  for fear that, so  how  ( I fear lest  )  I think logically is not correct to say :

I fear lest we should arrive

a. (lest) is not followed by a negative verb b. lest is usually followed by ( should or might )

I would rather suggest omitting ( lest ) and answer as :

I fear we should not arrive in season.

4. There is no one as wise that he does not sometimes make mistakes.

I suggest answering it as

There is no one as wise as  he that does not sometimes make mistakes .

Please review my suggestions and tell me whether my corrections are right or not.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you please distinguish your ideas of what is the "correct" text from your discussion of the texts. I think that the questions are not about knowing facts about animals or planets, but they are simply about grammer.

Comment: There is a problem...  The book you have is so old that the English it teaches is archaic.  For example I would say "Jupiter is almost **as** bright as Venus"  But I think in the English of 100 years ago, the word "so" might have been acceptable.  Now it seems odd and dated.  Similarly the word "lest" is not used in contemporary English (except in some old proverbs)  This is a problem for you.  The solution is to get rid of the old book and find a new one.

Comment: @JamesK I do not disagree that the book is obviously old, but I do not think that the advice being imparted is all that outdated. I still write "as bright as" rather than "so bright as" and reserve "so" for negative statements such as "not so bright as." Some may say that is being a bit old fashioned, but it is hardly archaic. I think the reason you find the English odd is that the exercise is to find errors. I would not call them errors in grammar so much as errors in usage. If you make the corrections contemplated, the seemingly archaic nature disappears.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm not sure what are intended to be errors and what are not.

Comment: 5. There is no one **so** wise that he does not sometimes make mistakes. I have corrections for all of them which IMO are not dated. Only the circumstance.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. One question per question is the SE rule. Had they all been based on the same 'error' fine, but they're not.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just do your work, I'll try to explain the "rules".

With comparisons of two things that are (almost) equal use as...as

> Peter is <s>so</s> as strong as Joe.

> Peter is not as strong as Joe.

When not making a comparison you can use "so", to mean "very".

> Peter is <s>as</s> so strong.

> Peter is not so strong.

> Peter is not so strong that he can lift a car.

This can also be used with negative words like "Nobody"

> Nobody is so strong.

Finally, the word "lest" is not used in Modern English, so the sentence with "lest" needs to rewritten completely.

The use of "we shall" and "we should" is also archaic.  In contemporary English this would be "we will" and "we would".

Comment: Thank you very much @James K  You are right   What about  Q  4   There is no one as wise that he does not sometimes make mistakes.    ?

Comment: There is no comparison in that sentence.

Comment: Because ( Jupiter is not as  bright as Venus ) I suggest the answer should be  :  Jupiter is nowhere near as  bright as Venus,   @James K  Notice the number 60  ((  Jupiter is almost 60 bright as Venus   ))  I picked from Google  as it is

Comment: If this is book about astronomy, then maybe that is right.  But this is about English grammar.  So "Jupiter is brighter than Venus" is *correct grammar*.  The truth or falsehood is irrelevant here.